# PowerShell - Return file search results with the ability to select which file you want to open

Tags: powershell

Here is my code which works but I'm not sure how to add the ability to number the results and select which file to open.

I'm not a programmer by no means it took me a week just to get this far so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
# Find pdf files by name on my network share then select one from the list of return matches to open 

Write-Host "Enter a File Name" 

$fileName = Read-Host

# Set the path to the folder you want to search
$folderPath = "\\MyNetworkShare"

$pdfFile = Get-ChildItem -path $folderPath  -Recurse -Filter *.pdf |Where-Object {$_.Name -match $fileName} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

# If there is a match, open the PDF in Microsoft Edge
if ($pdfFile)
{
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" $pdfFile
    Write-Host "$pdfFile"
    pause 10
}
else {
    Write-Host "File not found"
}
```

Current Output

```
Enter a File Name
465430
\\MyNetworkShare\Tk.465430.1668780736.001.pdf
Press Enter to continue...: 
PS C:\Users\timothy\Desktop\POWERSHELL>
```

I would like the output to be:

```
No File
-- ----
1  Tk.465430.1668780736.001.pdf
2  Tk.465430.1668780737.001.pdf
3  Tk.465430.1668780738.001.pdf

Select a file to open:
```

Comment: `Out-GridView -PassThru` is the easiest to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate through the files returned while assigning them their index number in the list of `$pdfFile`. Since im very fond of `PSCustomObjects` I will use that for the demonstration's purposes, but this can be done other ways with the simplest probably being piping to `Out-GridView`:

```
$fileName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a File Name'

# Set the path to the folder you want to search
$folderPath = '\\networkshare'
if ($pdfFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Filter "*$fileName*.pdf" -File -Recurse )
{
    & {
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $pdfFile.Count; $i++)
        {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                $('#' + (' ' * $pdfFile.Count.Length)) = $i + 1
                PDFName = '{0}' -f $pdfFile[$i].BaseName
                Created = '{0}' -f $pdfFile[$i].CreationTime
            }
        }
    } | Out-String -Stream
    $selection = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter PDF(s) to open') -split ',' | % 'Trim'
    foreach ($selected in $selection)
    {
        $pdf = $pdfFile[$selected - 1]
        Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" $pdf.FullName
        Write-Host $pdf
        pause 10
    }
}
else
{
    Write-Host -Object "No file with name `"$fileName`" found."
}
```

The code needed to run this should just be a `for` loop with a selection option, but due to how `Read-Host` beats the object output to the pipeline, there's some workarounds implemented. Also, starting the selection at 1 causes you to subtract by 1 on the selected since arrays start at 0.

Comment: Wow this is great except the file will not open because the full path is not being select when I select a file

Comment: Here is the result that comes out from your code and when I select 1

#  PDFName                  Created              
-- -------                  -------              
 1 Tk.459913.1667220377.001 11/28/2022 3:57:49 PM
 2 Tk.459914.1667221665.001 11/28/2022 3:57:50 PM

The Edge browser opens but does not open the pdf file it just shows this in the address box

http://tk.466155.1669045992.001.pdf/

For the file to open I believe we need the full path to be past to the browser like
\\MyNetworkShare\tk.466155.1669045992.001.pdf

Thank you so much for your time

Comment: @timothytech, my mistake. Add `.FullName` to it. So, it should be `Start-Process ... $pdf.FullName`.

Comment: I'm sorry but where exactly would I add .FullName ?

Comment: in your call to `Start-Process`. See my edit.

Comment: Is it possible to select more than one file to open?

Comment: @timothytech, it should be. I had already included it in the script as well. Just separate the #'s you select with a comma: `1, 23, 54`.